# Will changing the service interface for one class require updating the service references for all classes?

Tags: .net, wcf

I believe the answer to my question is no, but I want to double check.

I've got a WCF service I wrote a while ago, which is now in .NET 4.0 and I'm editing it with VS 2010. The name of the solution is ASICommon2, and it has various services (.svc) classes named Checkout.svc, SelectClients.svc, MRU.svc, etc. I made some necessary changes to the MRU.svc service, and it's interface, which I've done. These changes don't affect any of the other services in this solution. Now, back in the MTS/COM+ days, any change like this would mean that the whole solution (ASICommon2 in this case) would break binary compatibility, so new references would have to be made, etc. But I'm wondering if that's necessary for any client that's using some service from ASICommon2 other than the MRU.svc service? When setting a service reference in a Visual Studio project, you don't set it to ASICommon2; you set it to ASICommon2/Checkout.svc (for example). So, like I said, I suspect that no change in the service necessary is necessary, so long as that service reference isn't to ASICommon2/MRU.svc.

Am I correct about this?

Comment: You are correct. The users of the other services are not effected. The only thing that can break a .svc user is when you change the contract (model, method signature...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason you would have to update the others if you changed something in a common dependency (eg change a dataprovider or entity that is common to all services).

Otherwise, if the changes are strictly isolated to MRU then that's all that needs to update.